# Battery Capacity

Tags: voltage, batteries, capacity

I'm new here but I have read some interesting posts on this website so you all might be able to help me.
I need to calculate the battery capacity I need to run the device.
My load is 300mA at 20ms and 1mA for the rest of the time from 4 AA batteries.  If this test is running for 15 days, I need to calculate the voltage left on the battery after 15 days. Thanks for your time and let me know if anymore information is needed.

Edit: According to a comment below, the 300mA pulse occurs 35 times per minute.

Comment: So your loads will be 300mA for 20ms & 1mA for 900ms.  How often will that power be used in 15 days? Exactly which brand & model AA cells will you be using?

Comment: In one minute it will use it 35 times approximately. Toshiba AA batteries will be used.

Comment: What is the model id of the cells?  What is your battery pack output voltage & how will the cells be connected (in series? in parallel? in series & parallel?)

Comment: The cells will be connected in series. It starts around 6V. I dont have the model no right now.

Comment: Google the battery & find an image then post the url to it here.  I'll try to find a datasheet for it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Toshiba+AA+batteries&biw=1242&bih=594&tbm=isch&imgil=85HGbtWSUhizdM%253A%253BKReR-QDJDCG1BM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.emundia.com%25252Falkaline-batteries-aa-lr6-bp6-promo-pack-42-toshiba-blue-line-0258427&source=iu&pf=m&fir=85HGbtWSUhizdM%253A%252CKReR-QDJDCG1BM%252C_&usg=__Mh_j64knQev0u1tFyhDo9jBA7xw%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjRmquvv4LKAhUBRmMKHZDoB6wQyjcIMA&ei=tjuDVtHnM4GMjQOQ0Z_gCg#imgrc=85HGbtWSUhizdM%3A&usg=__Mh_j64knQev0u1tFyhDo9jBA7xw%3D

Comment: @Nathaniel  Is this an academic assignment?  What have you been able to figure out yourself so far?

Comment: No it is not an academic question. It is a project im working on and very new to the low power design applications. This will help me to design/optimize the control circuit and meet the goals for the project. http://www.powerstream.com/battery-capacity-calculations.htm I have some notes and is currently not in my possession but will post it later.

Comment: I think this is the datasheet:  http://www.toshiba-batteries-eu.com/sites/default/files/imagesfiles/Standard_Alkaline.pdf

Comment: I am still confused. Tell me if this is right. For 20 ms, 300 mA. Then, for 900 ms, 1mA. Then there is a period of time where the current is zero. This pattern repeats around 35 times per minute? Basically you just want to take the weighted average current, then divide mAh of battery by average current.

Comment: The current is never zero. 1mA is idle current, 300mA current under load. The current 300mA is pulled 35 times per minute for 20ms. please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: That's very different than what you first stated.

Comment: It is clear now. Please edit the original question. The part about the original that is confusing is where does the 900 ms fit in?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Done.

Comment: Your average power = 6.35 mW, average A=1.06mA, average resistance=5.67 kΩ.  The datasheet doesn't project beyond 1000 hours of service life, so I'd guess your battery life (with such a small load) will be greater than 1000 hours.  For comparison, 15 Days = 360 hours.  Bear in mind, your actual results may vary depending on many factors (e.g. battery age, charge level, temp, etc).

Comment: Thank You much, these nos are going to help with microcontroller design. My challenge is to actually design something that would last the battery life to 18 to 19 days with the load mentioned.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So 35 times per minute is a period of 1.714 seconds, or 1714 ms. During that period, the current is 300 mA for 20  ms, and 1 mA for 1694 ms. So the average is:

300 mA * 20 ms + 1 mA * 1694 ms = ~ 4.5mA.

Typical AA batteries are roughly 2000 mAh (depending on numerous details). So that is around 445 hours of battery life. 15 days is 360 hours. So that means 360/445 = 81% of the battery capacity will be consumed during the 15 day interval.

You will have to look at a battery discharge chart to come up with an estimate of cell voltage after 81% depletion. Off the top of my head I would guess 1.2V per cell, so a total of 4.8V remaining.

If you need a better estimate, you should refine the answer using data from the actual cell you plan to use. But don't be surprised if the real voltage differs slightly from what you predict, no matter how carefully you calculate everything.

Comment: I'm curious how you arrived at this notion "Off the top of my head I would guess 1.2V per cell,...".  Is that based on past experience, some rough calculation, or just a swag ;-)?  I might guess the V would be even lower than that if 81% of the charge was depleted.  Interestingly, 1.5V * .81 = 1.215V :)

Comment: I have several years of experience designing alkaline battery-powered products for mass production. I guess it is an educated guess. I use 1.1 V or 1.15 as kind of the minimum start up voltage. While the product is running, I would like it to run down to 0.9 or 0.8V per cell, but when it is starting to boot up, I would want to see at least 1.1 or 1.15V per cell. So 1.2 is about the lowest voltage I would consider to be higher than dead.

Comment: I don't know, but not much. It is important to distinguish between loaded voltage and open-circuit voltage. If you connect a load to an alkaline cell, say 200 mA on an AA cell, and run it down to 0.8V, then disconnect the load, the cell voltage will rebound to over 1V for sure. Maybe it will rebound all the way to 1.2V. But when you re-apply the load, it will go back down to 0.8V very quickly. Probably in seconds. You can keep doing this, but each time, it will rebound less, and decline more rapidly. So a loaded voltage of 1.2 is OK. But open circuit voltage of 1.2 = almost dead.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  I've seen 1.1V & 1.2V used as cut-off V for some devices.  Most sources that I've read say <= 0.9V is essentially useless for most devices as they require more force to do their work.  Any idea how much energy is actually left in a 2Ah cell that is at 1.1V?  I saw a gadget (Batteriser) once that had (I think) some kind of step-up voltage circuit in it--which I didn't think would do much good on a 1.1V cell.

Comment: That Batteriser website claims devices only use 20% of the capacity of an alkaline battery & leave the remaining 80% unused when they stop drawing power due to reaching a predetermined cut-off V. I think that is probably nonsense because designers use a cutoff V because not enough power is available to do the work that their device requires--but... we'll see how their product works after it comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Your average power = 27mW, average A = 4.45mA, average resistance = 1.3kΩ. I estimate your battery life (with such a small load) will be ~630 hours. For comparison, 15 Days = 360 hours. Bear in mind, your actual results may vary depending on many factors (e.g. battery age, charge level, temp, etc).

**Here are my calcs:**
6V * .3A * (.02*35*60/3600) = 0.021W = 21mW
6V * .001A * ((3600-(.02*35*60))/3600) = ~0.00593W = ~5.93mW
Total = ~27mW

27mW / 6V = ~0.004488333A = ~4.45mA
6V / 4.45mA = ~1336.8Ω = ~1.3kΩ = ~334Ω per cell

Looking at the Toshiba datasheet: http://www.toshiba-batteries-eu.com/sites/default/files/imagesfiles/Standard_Alkaline.pdf

Since they don't specify the mAh capacity of the cell, you can estimate that the service life of a 334Ω load will be ~630 hours.  Since 15 days is 360 hour, you can conservatively estimate the battery pack should last 26.25 days (630/360*15).  If you assume the battery capacity is 12 Wh (6V*2Ah), then the battery should provide power for ~18.5 days (12 Wh / 27mW / 24hrs).

Note:  The datasheet doesn't really provide sufficient data for your load to determine a voltage after 15 days of operation.

Comment: I think you made a mistake. You calculated a resistor value based on a 4-cell stack. But then you used that same resistor value in the datasheet, which is for one cell. To do it right, you need to divide your resistor value by 4 before going to the discharge chart in the datasheet. Your estimate of battery life is thus around 4x too high.

Comment: Good catch.  Thanks.  I'll edit my answer.  But, the 1.42kΩ will still have a 1000+ hours of service life, won't it?

Comment: There is still something very wrong. The average current is not 1mA. 300 mA * 0.02 seconds is 1.67 uAh. If you multiply that by 35 pulses per minute, * 60 minutes per hour, that is 3.5 mAh per hour. In other words, the contribution of the  high current pulses to the average current is 3.5 mA all by itself. So the total average current is around 4.5mA. This means it is like a 1k load on 4 cells or a 250 Ohm load on 1 cell, which translates to around 500 hours on the datasheet.

Comment: The average current must be over 1mA because the op later stated: "The current is never zero. 1mA is idle current, 300mA current under load. The current 300mA is pulled 35 times per minute for 20ms.". I think that means his circuit continuously draws 1mA except for when it draws the 300mA for 20mS (35x/min).  Btw, how are you calculating 1.67 uAh?  .02 sec x 35 times/min * 60 times per hr = 42 seconds per hour which then leads to 42s/3600s*.3A = 0.0035A = 3.5mAh.

Comment: Just multiply current * time to get amp hours. 300 mA = 0.3A. 20 ms = 20/1000/3600 = 5.6 uH. Then 5.6 uH * 0.3 A = 1.67 uAH. This happens 35 * 60 times per hour. The average current is roughly 4.5 mA, as I said.

Comment: uH means micro-Hours, not micro-Henrys.

Comment: I understood that, thanks.  I see now how & where I botched my math.  I made some corrections to my answer.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mkeith: Lowercase 'h' for hours as in Ah? It's not an SI unit so you may be off the hook. (It was right in your earlier comment.)

Comment: @transistor, when I went to type "uH," it just came out that way (probably out of habit). "uh" would have been better. Anyway, DIYser knew what I meant, so it is OK. Can't edit now. The micro-hour is not a time measurement I use very often, so...

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers show that the battery capacity is theoretically  adequate to supply your average load current for 15 days, you still have to worry about their ability to cope with your 300mA peak current demand towards the end of that time.

That's not typically answerable from battery data.

I would be tempted to drain a set of batteries at 45mA for 1.5 days (accelerated test) and look at its output voltage under 300mA discharge pulses before and after such drain.

This may constrain your choice of batteries, or alternatively, suggest adding a large reservoir capacitor to limit the voltage drop during short high-current discharges.

For example, 300mA * 0.02s = 0.006 Coulombs.
dQ = C * dV
So if you decide you can tolerate say 0.5V drop during a current pulse,
C  = dQ / dV = 0.006/0.5 = 0.012 Farads or 12,000 microfarads.

That could increase the effective life of batteries not well suited to large discharge currents when partially discharged.

Comment: I think it will be fine, unless they are really crappy batteries. Any garden variety alkaline AA battery should be OK. A 300 mA pulse will definitely create a voltage drop, but I don't think it will go below 900 mV per cell, even after 15 days. Of course, I am assuming room temperature. If it is an instrument buried in a snow cave at the North Pole or something then all bets are off.

Comment: @mkeith : You may well be right, But if 0.9V/cell isn't enough for reliable operation, it's as well to know early in the project, and have a Plan B.

Comment: @Brian Drummond - But, how much battery energy would a common .012F cap leak over the 15+ days.  Would it be worth the addition to the circuit?

Comment: Using 2 of these http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1880101.pdf the manufacturer states 428uA/capacitor or 0.85 mA. (I've seen others with the same spec). That's a worst case across temperature (after a 2 minute healing period) so typical figures for an undamaged capacitor are likely to be much lower. Worth mentioning but unlikely to matter in practice.